# Follow up to MANCOVA and any possible alternative analyses

Tags: categorical-data, manova, psychology, mancova

In my research, I have two categorical IVs and a DV:

- A factor with 4 levels (mindset, encompassing 4 mindsets)
- A factor with 2 levels (condition, encompassing 2 conditions)
- A DV which is a composite factor with 4 levels (4 subscales)

I followed up with a MANOVA test with a Roy-Bargman stepdown to find out how the significant IV was affecting the comp DV.
However, I also have a construct of interest which is a continuous variable. Theoretically, it should also have effects on the comp DV.

I did a MANCOVA including this continuous IV as a covariate, but get the exact same results essentially as a MANOVA. Any one have some better ideas about how I can go about this?

Answer (score 2):

I personally find that MANOVA and MANCOVA are not very useful methods of running multivariate analyses, particularly with the number of assumptions that must be met and the very limited way that the analysis can be constructed. For a detailed look at why, check out [this episode from Quantitude](https://quantitudepod.org/s2e09-manova-must-die/), aptly called "MANOVA Must Die". But that's not the bulk of your question. **What is more striking is that, as Sointu alluded to, you seem to only have one DV**. In that case, there is no reason at all to use this method, and a simple multiple linear regression would accomplish what you are looking for (using your two factors as predictors regressing on the DV you mentioned, and entering the other continuous predictor is also easily accomplished this way).

To the point you made about the estimates being the same between your MANOVA and MANCOVA, I can't really say for certain why that is the case without output from your analysis. But it could just be an error or it could be that the control variable doesn't partial out enough variance to matter. More info would be needed on that front.

Comment: +1 for the podcast only!

Comment: That podcast is a treasure trove of information. I'm thankful it exists given how few outlets there are for such topics.

Comment: A quick look at the content coverage seems to be appetizing indeed.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have 1 dependent variable, why are you using MANOVA? That's for multiple dependent variables. If you have 1 dependent variable with 4 levels, multinomial regression might be more suitable.

(Though from your other descriptions it sounds like you actually have 4 different continuous dependent variables that fall under the same higher-level construct, so MANOVA is probably the correct choice).

> I did a MANCOVA including this continuous IV as a covariate, but get the exact same results essentially as a MANOVA.

If you have set your model correctly, and your new covariate has no effect on DV and also nothing happens to the relationship between IV and DV, then in your data, the covariate is not related to your DV and also is not a confounder in the relationship between IV and DV, regardless of what theory says. There's really nothing to do about that. (Actually, it may be valuable information that the theory was not supported.)

Although, did you hypothesize a main effect of the covariate or (or also) that the covariate might affect the relationship between your original IV and the dependent? If the latter, maybe include an interaction between IV and covariate into the model and see what happens.